# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 29.0 failed 4 times in Synapse

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing, azure-synapse

I did some calculations in PySpark Notebook in Synapse in this format (not reproducible):

```
list_col= X.dtypes
X_array_col = spark.createDataFrame(list_col)\
    .withColumnRenamed("_1", "Colname")\
    .withColumnRenamed("_2", "TypeColumn")\
    .filter(col("TypeColumn").contains("array"))
tab_toPd = X_array_col.toPandas()
n_array = tab_toPd.count()["Colname"]
X2 = X
while n_array != 0:
    for index, row in tab_toPd.iterrows():
        colname = tab_toPd["Colname"][index]
        typename = tab_toPd["TypeColumn"][index]
        X2= X2.withColumn(colname, explode_outer(col(colname)))
        if "struct" in typename:
            X2= X2.select("*", colname + ".*").drop(colname)
    list_col= X2.dtypes
    df_OroCommerce_array_col = spark.createDataFrame(list_col)\
        .withColumnRenamed("_1", "Colname")\
        .withColumnRenamed("_2", "TypeColumn")\
        .filter(col("TypeColumn").contains("array"))
    tab_toPd = X_array_col.toPandas()
    n_array = tab_toPd.count()["Colname"]
```

I want to do a count on the table:

```
X2.count()
```

I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o967.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 29.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 29.0 (TID 202) (vm-cd401785 executor 2): org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file wasbs://xxx-prd-we-eventstore@1933851374948631570.z40.blob.storage.azure.net/xxx-prd-we-eventstore/kdxTAA==/kdxTAOJwY-A=.Partitioned.Parquet/PartitionId=cf3494bc-c19f-4e70-85c3-5561c102b483/1933851374948631570_0_0.snappy.Parquet
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:251)
```

I am quite new to Spark. I try to debug this error with Google with no success. Where does this error come from?

Answer (score 0):

> org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file

This kind of error will occur when you try to simultaneously read parquet file which has different schema.

From [Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#configuration) section of [Parquet Files](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html) in the official documentation of Apache Spark:

Spark's method for writing Parquet data is adjustable. The property **`spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat`** controls this. False is the default setting. If "true" is specified, Spark will follow the same schema.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I tried spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat", "true")" but it's not working. Do you have another idea?